# Dynamically Add class to Element using AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ng-class

I want to mimic something that I have done with `JQuery` using `AngularJS`.

Below is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dq21mkuL/) for it.

Three things I have done here.

1. Find the last element of the right column.
2. Pickup the attribute 'data-color' from it
3. Assign the value of the attribute as a class to the 'right-col'

Comment: @georgegeawg: The link is already there in the question. The text "fiddle" has a link to it. The question is already been answered too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ubqrah1w/

It uses an angular directive.

```
.directive('lastColor', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    $element.addClass(angular.element($element[0].querySelector('.items:last-child')).attr('data-color'));
    }
  }
  });
```

Comment: Well doesnt work if i add the JS in a seperate file.. or in fiddle in the JS page.https://jsfiddle.net/ubqrah1w/1/

Comment: you have to load the javascript in the body, check this https://jsfiddle.net/yLtq1296/

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by angular'js directive (re-usable component) moreover angular has jqlite (jQuery library), as below.

**directives**:

```
app.directive('dynamicColor',dynamicColor);

    dynamicColor.$inject = [];

    function dynamicColor(){

      return{
        restrict:'A',
        link:function(scope,element,attrs){
          element.css('background-color',attrs.dynamicColor);
        }
      }

    }
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/Op5fI5oFQku07tkebBcg?p=preview

Comment: thanks a lot :) ur right.. but the above one was to the point.. but thanks a lot dude..